# How do the police know all this at the end of "Promising Young Woman"?

Tags: plot-explanation, promising-young-woman

At the end of *Promising Young Woman*,

> when the police comes to arrest Al, how do they know he is the killer?

I can imagine they discovered the necklace and what remained of the body, but at this point wouldn't everybody at the party be a suspect? The video of Nina can at best make him the main suspect. Before the police arrests him, I think they would at the least need to talk with everybody at the party.

Answer (score 3):

[As explained by EW](https://ew.com/movies/promising-young-woman-ending-explained/):

> He's ultimately arrested **because Cassie had a backup plan (a cache of incriminating emails and texts set to disperse in the event of her death)**, but the ending still stings — and that's exactly what Fennell wanted.

[Variety details](https://variety.com/2021/film/news/promising-young-woman-ending-spoilers-2-1234885400/):

> As a Plan B, **she’s sent evidence of Nina’s sexual assault to Al’s former lawyer (Alfred Molina), who would very much like to repent for the choices he made as an attorney years ago.** Whatever Cassie sent as proof of her disappearance (we never see it), the police find her remains.

Comment: I can understand she had evidence but she couldn't have provided evidence of who the killer is.

Comment: @martinkunev Not only did she collect evidence, she had potentially very incriminating material from the lawyer.